# Expected value of the largest eigenvalue after removing a vertex in a Markov Chain

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, reference-request, markov-chains

Assume we have a finite irreducible aperiodic Markov Chain represented by the matrix $A$ and we take the $i$-th vertex out (i.e. remove the corresponding column and row) obtaining $A_{-i}$.

> **Question:** Is there much* that can be said about the largest eigenvalue $\lambda_{max}(A_{-i})$ of $A_{-i}$, assuming the graph of $A_{-i}$ is connected, apart from $0<\lambda_{max}(A_{-i})<1$ ?
>
> What about $\sum_j\lambda_{max}(A_{-j})$?

*as in estimates, or explicitly as a function of the largest eigenvalue of $A$, its associated eigenvector and the deleted column and row.

Comment: You probably meant largest eigenvalue different from $1$. Is that the case?

Comment: @Radost If I'm not mistaken after the removal of a row and a column the matrix is no longer stochastic, hence the largest eigenvalue is smaller than one

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood what removing a vertex meant. Thanks for clarification.